# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()

Tags: c#

What is the difference between ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() and ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()?

Comment: What is the context here that [this C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript#System_Web_UI_ClientScriptManager_RegisterStartupScript_System_Type_System_String_System_String_) runs in? .NET code that runs under [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), generating HTML content with embedded JavaScript? Shouldn't it be tagged correspondingly, e.g. with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 7):

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` is for passing in a block of script which is automatically run at startup.

`ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` is just for registering a general method.

I think the technical difference is that the startup script is placed just before the `</body>` so that it is executed as soon as possible after the page is loaded?

## Update

I have double checked this and it is is what I said.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` "The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` "The RegisterClientScriptBlock method adds a script block to the top of the rendered page."

Comment: confirmed tests `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script2", test2)` is added at the top after viewstate. and `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script1", test1);` is added at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` places the script just before the closing `</body>` tag while `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` places it in the beginning, just after the viewstate hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN:

The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised.

The RegisterClientScriptBlock method adds a script block to the top of the rendered page.

etc