# Calling Javascript function from code behind ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, code-behind

I'm attempting to call a javascript method in its own file from code behind on a button click.

aspx file

```
protected void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hidden.Value == "")
    {
        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>drawImage();</script>");
    }
}
```

js file

```
function drawImage() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
    var imgBase = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    document.getElementById("hidden").value = imgBase;
}
```

The problem is that this wont call the draw image method, i suspect it's cause the js file is its own file but i'm not sure.

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

try this

```
string jquery = "drawImage();"
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", 
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+ jquery +"</script>"
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you already included the script file in your page.

If you require the postback, you need [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Type, String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) ..

```
protected void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hidden.Value == "")
    {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 'startupScript', 'drawImage();', true);
    }
}
```

[More Info from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520164/clientscript-registerstartupscript)

---

You can call the function from your button itself, without the postback.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID='next' OnClientClick="return drawImage();" />
```

and in the script

```
function drawImage() {
    if(document.getElementById("hidden").value != undefined || document.getElementById("hidden").value != "")
    {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
        var imgBase = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        document.getElementById("hidden").value = imgBase;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1). If the function is stored in external file (e.g. `MyScript.js`) then you should include it in the `<head>` section of the web page and add `onclick` event to the button, like:

```
ButtonName.Attributes.Add("onclick", {YourFunction});
```

in `Page_Load` event.

2) Another approach is to assign the entire javascript function to a string variable and then pass it instead of {YourFunction} prefixed with `javascript:`. In this case you don't even need the external file.

Hope it will help.
My best, Alex