# How do I call this script from code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to call this script from code behind but I am not sure on how to do it and all examples I have found include some overload that does not fit in this case.

The script:

```
        function Refresh(sender, eventArgs) {
            $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
    }
```

My attempt:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Refresh", true);
```

but it does not compile, "Unknow method registering ClientScriptBlock(...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter of ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock should be valid JavaScript. Try this instead:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Refresh", "Refresh();", true);
```

Comment: I still have the entire portion of the code line between brackets "this.Get------true"showing up in red "Unknow method registering

Comment: Try it now - I was looking at the documentation for ClientScriptManager, not ScriptManager :-S

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string jquery = "Refresh();"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+ jquery +"</script>");
```

source:

[Calling Javascript function from code behind ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410968/calling-javascript-function-from-code-behind-asp-net)