# Call to Java Script function in ASP page not returning anything

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    function EdgeCheck(){
        var edge1;
    var edge2;
    var sBrowser;
    edge1 = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
    edge2 = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1;
    if  ((edge1) || (edge2)){
    sBrowser = 'You are using Edge Browser';
    //alert(sBrowser);
    }
    return sBrowser;
    }    
</script>

<% response.write("<b><font size='6' color='#008080'>" + '<script>EdgeCheck();</script>' + "</font></b>") %>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the function isn't being called at all, or is it just not printing the returned text?

Comment: Calling a JS function from ASP? You know ASP is a server-side language and JS is a client-side language, right? These two languages execute at different times and on different machines, they have no business with each other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: As kenput3r said above are you actually calling the JS at all or are you not just printing out <script>EdgeCheck();</script>. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410968/calling-javascript-function-from-code-behind-asp-net to se the cotrrect way to call the JS..

Comment: It is calling the function. When I uncomment the alert the alert pops up